# ember data relationships and ready/loaded event

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, relationships, dirty-data

Until ember data [has built-in dirty relationship tracking](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/21), we have rolled our own. After upgrading to Ember/Ember Data 2.4.3 (from something quite old), our custom solution stopped working.

The problem comes down to knowing when to make a snapshot of a record's relationship state as the "original" state against which we can compare later states.

Let's say an adapter's payload includes the following:

```
{
    id: 'post-1',
    type: 'post',
    relationships: {
        comments: {
            data: [{ type: 'comment', id: 'comment-1' }]
        }
    }
}
```

In the `ready` hook for the resulting record, and using the new references API, I'd expect to be able to say something like:

```
ready: function() {
    var commentIds = this.hasMany('comments').ids();
    // would expect commentIds to be ['comment-1']
}
```

But this seems not to work -- `commentIds` is an empty array.

(Note that observing the `isLoaded` property also doesn't seem to give me what I want—the record is already in the `loaded` state when the `ready` event fires.)

Basically I'd like to have something like a `relationshipsLoaded` event which is fired when a record's relationships have been populated *with respect to an adapter's payload*. The related records themselves may not be available or loaded, but that shouldn't impact the record's state of having a relationship, based on the data returned from an adapter.

After some spelunking I've found that hooking into the store's backburner will provide something that seems to work:

```
ready: function() {
    this.store._backburner.schedule('finished', this, function() {
        var commentIds = this.hasMany('comments').ids();
        // commentIds is now ['comment-1']
    });
}
```

But this is obviously sketchy and I'm not sure that it's really *guaranteeing* what I'd like it to be guaranteeing.

So: is there a real way to do this? A better way? Is this a feature that is forthcoming?

For reference I made a codepen illustration: https://codepen.io/patternleaf/pen/Vazdxj